# NodeJS - const/variable evaluation doesn't work

Tags: node.js

[Accordingly to NodeJS documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/console.html#console_console)

```
console.log('hello world');
// Prints: hello world, to stdout
console.log('hello %s', 'world');
// Prints: hello world, to stdout
console.error(new Error('Whoops, something bad happened'));
// Prints: [Error: Whoops, something bad happened], to stderr

const name = 'Will Robinson';
console.warn(`Danger ${name}! Danger!`);
// Prints: Danger Will Robinson! Danger!, to stderr
```

But this never works anywhere, if you consider running the following simple code in REPL (online or locally):

```
const x = '10';
console.log("x value is ${x}"); // Always prints ${x}, but never the evaluated value
```

May be I am missing something here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to console log it as a string, you need to use template literals.

```js
const x = '10';
console.log(`x value is ${x}`);


console.log('hello world');
// Prints: hello world, to stdout
console.log('hello %s', 'world');
// Prints: hello world, to stdout
console.error(new Error('Whoops, something bad happened'));
// Prints: [Error: Whoops, something bad happened], to stderr

const name = 'Will Robinson';
console.warn(`Danger ${name}! Danger!`);
```

Template literal documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: it's the back-tick! fool me once (shame on JS), and once only! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to answer from @NicolaeMaties I overlooked what's in the first 3 sentences.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Description

It's the **Back Tick** grave accent, NOT single quote. But I still believe that NodeJS documentation could perhaps state the obvious (!) one more time.